# ComputeError with polars dataframe while trying to chain expressions in a single with_columns_seq operation

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to do a series of operations on a single column in a lazy polars DataFrame and I am trying to avoid using `with_columns_seq` repeatedly in doing so, but there's a `ComputeError` stating a duplicate column name. Is there a better alternative to this?

```py
df = (
    df
        .with_columns_seq([
            pl.col('sentiment').cast(pl.UInt8),
            pl.col('review').map_elements(lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x).get_text()),
            pl.col('review').str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " "),
            pl.col('review').str.to_lowercase(),
            # pl.col('review').str.split_by(' ')
        ])
    
)

df.collect().head()
```

and the error is

```
ComputeError: the name: 'review' passed to `LazyFrame.with_columns` is duplicate

It's possible that multiple expressions are returning the same default column name. If this is the case, try renaming the columns with `.alias("new_name")` to avoid duplicate column names.
```

tried to compose all operations but failed due to a duplicate column error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Explanation

Your error message tells you already almost everything to grasp the problem:

> It's possible that multiple expressions are returning the same default column name. If this is the case, try renaming the columns with `.alias("new_name")` to avoid duplicate column names.

However, it does not in this case actually suggest a solution that you probably want.

The error comes because each of the lines starting with `pl.col("review")` creates a new column `review`, because `.with_columns_seq` does not mean that you run an each of those expressions to updated data one after another. It just means that parallel processing is not used to do this operation, and you might as well just use `with_columns`.

The usual solution would be to use `alias("new_name")`, like the error message helpfully suggests. However, in your situation it would just create two columns with slightly differing data

```
        .with_columns_seq([
            pl.col('review').map_elements(lambda x: x),
            pl.col('review').str.to_lowercase().alias("lowercase"),
        ])
```

```
┌───────────┬──────────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ sentiment ┆ review               ┆ lowercase            │
│ ---       ┆ ---                  ┆ ---                  │
│ i64       ┆ str                  ┆ str                  │
╞═══════════╪══════════════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ 1         ┆ I love this movie    ┆ i love this movie    │
│ 0         ┆ I hate this movie!!  ┆ i hate this movie!!  │
...
```

This seems to be not something you want. Instead you need a way to do each of those operations to the new `review` column sequantially.

#### Solution

To actually run these expressions for `review` sequentially, you [pipe them together](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/concepts/expressions/#examples).

> The power of expressions is that every expression produces a new expression, and that they can be piped together. You can run an expression by passing them to one of Polars execution contexts.

So you would do this instead:

```
df = (
    df
        .with_columns([
            pl.col('sentiment').cast(pl.UInt8),
            pl.col('review').map_elements(lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x).get_text())
                .str.replace_all(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ")
                .str.to_lowercase()
        ])
    
)
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't realize we could chain operations on a column. works perfect.